# Curl function not working in XAMPP 1.8.0

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I am using Windows 7. I have installed XAMPP 1.8.0 and also enabled the CURL functionality. But, I am still not able to crawl web pages.

**I used the following code segment:**

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

 // grab URL and pass it to the browser
 curl_exec($ch);

 // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```

**And when I executed the program, the error message was:**

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\curl.php on line 14
```

**Line 14:** `curl_close($ch)`

Why I am getting such an error? How can I debug it? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `set_time_limit($seconds);` in your page

also

add `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);` and try

Comment: Edited the answer please check it :)

Comment: Ref link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935710/time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-error-file-get-contents

Comment: [code]
     <?php
// create a new cURL resource
set_time_limit(120);[/code]
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch)or die(curl_errno($ch).":Cannot execute it");

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>[/code]